# MS Access macro

Tags: sql, macros, ms-access-2010

I’m looking for some help to create a simple macro. I have a table(Orders) with OrderNo*, PO, and Amount which is displayed in a Form (Open Orders)

However I would like to create a macro that when I click on the PO it will open that specific record on a separate form (Order Details).

The input for PO is a text box.

Thank you.